# how to recover lost encrypted partition (bitlocker)?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

I resized one of my partitions using AOMEI. After a reboot my encrypted partition, which I did not resize, disappeared. I tried to fix it with [DISKPART](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GokK9.png) but that didn't work. I can see the lost partition with [DISKMGMT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sCoT.png) where I am given no option but delete to delete it.

Is there anyway to fix or recover my encrypted partition? I have not deleted it, it is just not appearing.

Comment: You should have decrypted your HDD before you changed the size of the partition, since you didn't do this, you made data recovery not possible.

Comment: ty for reply .. i didn't resize the encrypted partition .. i resized another 2 partitions that's why iam wondering why it's effected

Comment: My guess the tool you used caused the problem

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There are many bootable recovery software. Almost all of them come packaged with GNU ddrescue.

*From iboyd:*

> Removing the disk drive from the laptop/PC and connecting it via USB
>   to another Win7/8 PC will allow you to attempt to access the data with
>   the Recovery Key.
>
> If this fails or has problems, RIPLinux with DDRescue can make a copy
>   of the data to another disk in the hope that you can gain access to
>   the data from this new disk.

This might help you out:

1. http://cobaltfish.com/techie/308-recovering-bitlocker-partition
2. http://iboyd.net/index.php/2012/09/08/recovering-data-from-a-failing-bitlocker-hard-drive/

Comment: Thank you Dhruvan Ganesh & iboyd for your answer
i've tried to open my harddisk in another pc and the partition appeared and decrypted it and transfered all my files to another partition .. and still the lost partition didn't show up even after i formatted it .. but that's ok i saved my files ... Thanks again!